# Connect AWS Amplify React Dashboard to backend services in private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amazon-vpc

I have created a private subnet in a VPC with a couple of private RDS databases and microservices to retrieve handle request from a react dashboard deployed using AWS amplify.

While I can use security groups to restrict access to different private subnet resources, I am having difficulty creating a secure connection between the Amplify front end and the Private VPC backend.

I have used AWS API gateway service to route requests to the subnet microservice.
I have spoken to a solution architect who suggested a VPC endpoint could solve the problem, but it seems that this just helps with internal communication within the private VPC.

I have tried creating a HTTP API VPC link, but I am not sure how to test if it is working.

I have tried creating a REST API VPC link  but I am having difficulty setting up a working network load balancer to connect it to.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how set up a secure connection

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't connect between your front-end, which sits on your user's browser, directly with backend resources on a private subnet. What Amplify does is use Cloudfront to distribute your react front end to user browsers. It's not responsible to help the front-end communicate with other non-Amplify related back-end services.

You could consider the following instead:

1. You will need to connect to the private service in your private subnet via a **public** endpoint on a **public** subnet.
2. The front end code (from the user browser or mobile app) will send a request to this public endpoint along with authorization token (after user authentication).
3. This public endpoint, which will receive the request via an **Application** Load Balancer or API gateway will then relay the user request to the RestFUL services sitting in your private subnet.
4. I also recommend you develop a RestFUL backend service to handle R/W requests to the database.

For secure communication, you can allow only HTTPS requests to keep user traffic encrypted. Hope this helps.